# move from Listbox to other ListBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<table width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
<asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="Responsabilidades"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstDisponibles" runat="server" Width="140px" 
            Height="110px" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem>s</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>w</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>f</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="imgAdd" type="image" src="../../images/control_fastforward.png" value="button" />                                   
        <br />
        <input id="imgRem" type="image" src="../../images/control_rewind.png" value="button" />                                   
    </td>
    <td>
       <asp:ListBox ID="lstUsuario" runat="server" Width="140px" Height="110px" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        </asp:ListBox>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**and the jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgAdd").click(function () {
        $("#lstDisponibles > option[@selected]").appendTo("#lstUsuario");
    });
    $("#imgRem").click(function () {
        $("#lstUsuario > option[@selected]").appendTo("#lstDisponibles");
    });
});
```

I want to move from lstDisponibles to lstUsuarios but this dont work.
I can find any example using asp.net listbox element. I test using  html tag but this cannot be useful.

Anyone can please helpme with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your selector from:

```
#lstDisponibles > option[@selected]
```

to:

```
#lstDisponibles > option:selected
```

Add would be:

```
$("#lstUsuario").append($("#lstDisponibles > option:selected"));
```

Comment: dont work friend, I am using a masterpage. I use this code <%=lstUsuario.UniqueID %> and dont work

Comment: @haggar View the source and look at the id attribute of your list box, what is it?

Comment: <select size="4" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lstUsuario" multiple="multiple" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstUsuario" class="targetSelect" style="height:110px;width:140px;">

Comment: Use <%=lstUsuario.ClientID %>. It will give you the asp.net generated id.

Comment: dont work my friend I can see why.  $().ready(function()
        {
            $("#imagenAgregar").click(function () {
                $('<%=listBoxResponsabilidades.ClientID %> option:selected').appendTo('<%=listBoxResponsabilidadAsignada.ClientID%>');
        return false;
    });

    $("#imagenQuitar").click(function () {
        $('<%=listBoxResponsabilidadAsignada.ClientID %> option:selected').appendTo('<%=listBoxResponsabilidades.ClientID %>');
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: There seems to be a few things wrong with what you just pasted in. .appendTo('<%=listBoxResponsabilidadAsignada.ClientID%>') for one...are you new to jQuery? I suggest that you take a step back and try fixing one thing at a time.

Comment: yes I am new to jQuery, this become a little bit hard for me.

Comment: Hi I solve adding the following under a master page.<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#aspnetForm").ready(function ()
        {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_listBoxResponsabilidadAsignada").append($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_listBoxResponsabilidades > option:selected"));
    });
});          
       
    </script>

Comment: <input id="imgAdd" type="image" src="../../images/control_fastforward.png" value="button" />  input need be type="button" this fire my other jQuery validators. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, it looked like you might have bitten off a lot to chew at once. One further thing...you can change $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_listBoxResponsabilidadAsignada") to $('#<%=listBoxResponsabilidadAsignada.ClientID %>')...this will save you in the future if any of the IDs of the content placeholders change. ClientID will generate that long name for you. If you have trouble with it at all, remember to check the html markup...nothing is magic ;) Just use the ClientID property of controls whenever you need the id of a .Net control in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

They syntax should be

```
$("#lstDisponibles > option:selected")
```

Also be careful that .net isn't changing your IDs.